# CSS + jquery responsive background color changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The goal I'd like to achieve is that, if the window size is greater than 400, the `#box2` color changes to black (when onhover on `#box1`), if smaller than 400, `#box2` color changes to yellow.

I thought I finished this task, however I found I always need to refresh the page to see the effects. the jQuery doesn't work immediately once the window size changes.

Do I need to use ajax or something to make the jQuery responsive to work?

Online Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/dFbXr/

here is my code

```
HTML:
    <div id="box1">
        <div id="box2"></div>
    </div>

jQuery:
    function colorchange(){
     if($(window).width() > 400){
        $("#box1").mouseover(function(){
        $("#box2").css('background','black');
         }).mouseout(function(){
             $("#box2").css('background','blue');
     });
      }else{
     $("#box1").mouseover(function(){
     $("#box2").css('background','yellow');
    }).mouseout(function(){
          $("#box2").css('background','blue');
    });
    }
    }      

    colorchange();

CSS:
    #box1{
        display: block;
        background:red;
        background-size: 100%;
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 60%;
    }

    #box2{
        display:block;
        background:blue;
        position:absolute;
        height:70px;
        width:70px;
        right:50%;
        top:50%;
        margin: -35px -35px 0 0;
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call your `colorchange()` function both when the page first loads and when the window is resized. There is a "resize" event that you can handle with code like this:

```
$(window).on("resize",colorchange);
```

Note that `colorchange` is passed as a parameter to the [`.on()` function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) *without* parentheses, i.e., `colorchange` not `colorchange()`. Without parens passes a reference to the function, with parens calls the function immediately and passes its result.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dFbXr/1/

You mentioned Ajax, but Ajax is totally unrelated to the problem at hand: it is for sending and/or receiving data from the web server without reloading the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

You're only calling the `colorchange()` function once--you need to call it again any time the window is resized, otherwise it will only have gone through your if-else once.

You need to add this jQuery to your code:

```
$(window).on("resize",colorchange);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only supporting `CSS3` browsers and don't want to rely on JavaScript, you could use media query to achieve the same thing, by changing the effect of the `:hover` by screen size.

Here's a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/dFbXr/2/